# I get the already asked question when I hit "Ask question"?

Tags: support

This morning I asked [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/144201/charset-issue-in-a-webform) question and it was published well (well, at least I got that impression). Now, I needed to ask another question and when I hit `Ask Question` I got in the textarea the question I asked in the morning. What's this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply click discard draft that's it.

Comment: I know I can do that, but why did that happen? Was it a glitch?

Comment: @Kartagis I raised earlier http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213030/not-able-to-ask-new-question-in-drupal-meta